# Setting UTF-8 encoding on handle.exe?

Tags: windows, powershell, encoding

I'd like to get process ID which including Japanese characters in opening filenames.

For that, I tried to that with handle.exe. But as below result, I got non-encoded characters.  How do you solve this issue?

```
$OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.UTF8Encoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.UTF8Encoding

PS C:\pg\20190105072154> echo "あいうえお"
あいうえお
PS C:\pg\20190105072154> handle64.exe -p vlc.exe| sls "mp3"

  6A8: File  (RW-)   E:\_videos\_youtube_dl\_soundcloud_likes_you\85351791--????? - DAYS of DASH(Visko Remix)--Visko.mp3
```

Comment: Try to also set `[console]::InputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.Utf8Encoding`

Comment: `handle64.exe` simply cannot deal with Unicode characters in filenames, my best guess is because it internally calls the wrong Win32 API functions. I don't think there is anything you can do to make `handle64.exe` work.

Comment: There is the PoshInternals Powershell Module: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PoshInternals, it contains a `Handle.ps1` file that looks like it's able to extract file handles with paths directly from the Win32 API, if you want to try this.

Comment: IIRC handle.exe hard codes using either the ANSI or OEM codepage, in which case changing the console codepage won't help. In Windows 10, we can set the system locale codepage to UTF-8 (65001) for the ANSI/OEM codepages. Otherwise handle.exe can't handle this.